# Stripe doubles anything

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using a function I created that I have tried creating customers from, and creating charges from. For whatever reason it seems to be double charging in test mode (Not bringing into live mode under these conditions) and I'm trying to understand why. I had it going through a few functions so I made it all happen in one function to make sure that it had nothing to do with what I had made. I'm lost on why this is happening. I try to make charges from token, doubles in less than a second. I try to create a customer from token, doubles in less than a second. I am using Stripes latest stripe-php library.

```
public function invoice($invoice = null) {
    //Provides billing info for invoice.ctp
    $this->loadModel('Invoice');
    $billingi = $this->Invoice->get($invoice, [
        'contain' => ['Items'],
    ]);

    $dollars = 0;
    foreach ($billingi->items as $item) {
        $dollars += $item->price;
    }
    $cents = bcmul($dollars, 100);
    $price = floatval($cents);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $stripeToken = $this->request->data('stripeToken');
        //Sets stripe API 
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_QVYouMViTf1k3zfVu2VAyZge");
        //Retrieves stripe token from stripe API
        //$response = \Stripe\Token::retrieve($stripeToken);

        \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            "description" => "Test customer",
            "source" => $stripeToken // obtained with Stripe.js
        ));
        $this->Flash->success(__('Thank you for your payment!'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'approved', $invoice]);
    }

    /*
      if ($response && $this->checkExists($response->card->cvc_check, $response->card->address_zip_check) == true) {
      $this->insertCharge($invoice, $response, $price);
      } else {
      //Throw error because cvc_check or zip came back null (doesn't exist)
      }
      }

     */
    $this->set('billingi', $billingi);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['billing']);
}
```

The reason why there are things commented out is because I wanted to test the function without it, but adding it back later when I understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the only API request sent to Stripe is a [customer creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) request (`\Stripe\Customer::create(...)`).

This doesn't charge the user -- it merely validates the card from the token in the `source` parameter, and creates a persistent customer object that you can in turn use to create actual charges. [This tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later) explains this flow.

There's nothing in your code that would cause the API request to be sent twice. It's very unlikely the issue is on Stripe's end. More likely, your code is being called twice for some reason that's not related to Stripe. You'd need to add traces to your code to figure out what exactly is being called in what order.